# Will process be allocated enough heap when no explicit parameters are specified?

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, jvm

I am running java process through main class on java 8. I have not specified anywhere min(Xms) and max(Xmx) heap size. But when i check through visualVM it's
4267704320(i.e. 4.26 GB) which is the default max heap size for a given process(confirmed through windows command also which is
`-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version 2>&1 | findstr MaxHeapSize`. similarly on linux box too).

**My question is** if my process(on linux machine) requires more 5 GB(i have 30 GB RAM), will my process be allocated 5 GB memory  when i have not specified
 any explicit heap size(Xms and Xmx) parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your the available RAM on your machine, if you are running a 64-bit JVM in server mode, then yes, the heap size will be able to go up to approximately 7.5 GB.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html#default_heap_size) (I highlighted the relevant parts):

> **Client JVM Default Initial and Maximum Heap Sizes**
>
> The default maximum heap size is half of the physical memory up to a physical memory size of 192 megabytes (MB) and otherwise ***one fourth of the physical memory*** up to a physical memory size of 1 gigabyte (GB).
>
> **Server JVM Default Initial and Maximum Heap Sizes**
>
> ***The default initial and maximum heap sizes work similarly on the server JVM as it does on the client JVM***, except that the default values can go higher. On 32-bit JVMs, the default maximum heap size can be up to 1 GB if there is 4 GB or more of physical memory. ***On 64-bit JVMs, the default maximum heap size can be up to 32 GB*** if there is 128 GB or more of physical memory. You can always set a higher or lower initial and maximum heap by specifying those values directly; see the next section.

Again, assuming a 64-bit JVM running in server mode, the default max heap size according to the documentation will be one fourth of your total RAM. So approximately 7.5 GB in your case (1/4 of 30 GB).

If running a 32-bit JVM in server mode, you'll be capped at 1 GB.  And in client mode, your max will be 256 MB.

Comment: For 64-bit JVMs, there is no other than server mode. And since the OP already stated that the JVM uses 4GB max memory, it must be a 64 Bit JVM. By the way, in practice, 32 Bit JVMs manage to use more than 1 GB.

Comment: @Holger: Thank you. It wasn't clear to me if the 4GB max mentioned by OP was in Windows only or also in Linux.

Comment: @sstan  Two follow up question 1) what if 3GB is already taken by another process. Then I believe default memory allocated will be to second process will be 7.5-3=4.5 GB. Right ? 2) Say I start first java process without any explicit heap size options. so as per your answer default allocated max heap will be 7.5 to this process. Now if want to run another java process which requires 2 GB heap. Will I be able to start second process. I believe answer should no as 7.5 GB memory has already been reserved for first process. Is that correct ?

Comment: @sstan can you please reply on mine last comment ?